# Ошибка при авторизации на сайт

Tags: django

При отправке формы для авторизации выдает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

views.py

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.get_user()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('news')
else:
    form = UserLoginForm()
return render(request, 'news/login.html', {"form": form})
```

forms.py

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
username = forms.CharField(label='Имя пользователя',help_text='Тут нужно ввести имя пользователя', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Comment: в ошибке: логин принимает 1 аргумент, а вы ему суёте 2. login(request, user)

Comment: Переименуйте свою view-функцию, вместо login напишите что-нибудь другое

Comment: Спасибо, поменял название и все заработало